# Trying to change/add border and colors to Zxinq QR activity

Tags: android, zxing

I'm trying to add/change the color of the laser and the border.
I've tried to override the colors via colors.xml using the following code but it doesn't work. I don't have a layout for the scanning activity. I'm still new at this but I did some research about it. Do I have to import the Zxing module locally and edit the ViewfinderView in order for it to work?
Thanks

```
<color name="viewfinder_mask">#60000000</color>
<color name="viewfinder_laser">#ffcc0000</color>
<color name="viewfinder_border">#00d1cf</color>
```